# How to check current pm.max_children setting?

Tags: php, apache, server

In error log i found warnings something like that

> WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it

So I changed it in conf file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf to 52 after some recommended calculations.
After this I restarted apache and I thought that problem was resolved. But right now I see again in error log file same warning with same value 10.

So I have a question - how can I check current pm.max_children? If it is not 52 then I will try to inspect why it is not applying.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post, surely you have already solved it in the meantime. In any case, maybe the problem was that you also had to restart php-fpm to make the changes effective with something like this:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```